# Do I need to create ATA for TokenAccount

Tags: anchor, rust, pda, associated-token-account, anchor-spl

library:

```
use anchor_spl::token::{ Token, TokenAccount, Transfer }
```

Token Account:

```
 #[account(
     mut,
     seeds = [mint.key().as_ref(), b"nfts_vault_seed", from.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub nfts_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Do I need to create `associated_token` if I need to store tokens in `TokenAccount` or can I directly transfer tokens? In case I need to create an associated token then what to pass in authority? My wallet address or TokenAccount?

```
  associated_token::create(
      CpiContext::new(
         ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
         associated_token::Create {
           payer: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
           associated_token: ctx.accounts.nfts_vault.to_account_info(),                    
           authority: ctx.accounts.????????, //what to pass here?
           mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
           system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
           token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
           rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        },
       ),
      )?;
```

Transfer:

```
token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.nfts_vault.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
                }
            ),
            1
        )?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by setting `authority` as a PDA address in the token account.

Token Account

```
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [mint.key().as_ref(), b"nfts_vault_seed", from.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        //space = 82,
        payer = from, 
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = stake_account, //THIS authority is PDA  
    )]
    pub nfts_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Transfer:

```
token::transfer(
       CpiContext::new(
          ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
          token::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.nfts_vault.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
          }
       ),            1
)?;
```